# Need some opinion about multiple power source switching

Tags: power-supply

I designed a simple circuit, which does the following.
Two voltage sources are attached, 5V USB plug and 7.5 V wall adapter with barrel jack plug.
5V USB source should get disconnected when 7.5 V source is active.
There will be another step-up converter (pololu 2115) on the output to bring the ca. 4.2 V output to the final voltage of 5 V.
I do not want to use the the barrel jack switch, because this would disconnect USB even if there is no power attached to the barrel jack plug.

So I use a single p-mosfet to do the job and it seems to work in general, except
for quite significant voltage and current spikes at the moment of switching the 7.5 V on and off. I made only a LTSpice simmulation without proper osciloscope.

Now my question is: Is it a usable solution? Should I care about the spikes? If I shoud care, how can I improve the response without a dedicated power path controler IC (which I know they exist)?

I attache the LTSpice circuit and the transient response graph as images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using larger capacitors at the output, say `100uF`, or so? BTW, that `C2` across `V2`, for the simulation purpose, is uselss, unless you have specified `Rser` in `V2`.

Comment: Adding larger capacitor C1 (way above 100u) doesn't change almost anything for the voltage under the simulated load of ca. 0.5 A. But it produces a large inrush current spike up to several amps through D2.